# Hidden div is doing validation

Tags: javascript, html

In this two radio buttons are present.

On click of this buttons a div is show and hide.

On click of submit button validation occurs.

When the div is visible validation is happening.

But when the div is hidden the validation is also occurring.

How to prevent validation on hidden div.

This is my code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function checkRadio(frmName, rbGroupName)
{ 
    var radios = frmName.elements[rbGroupName]; 
    for (var i=0; i <radios.length; i++)
    { 
        if (radios[i].checked)
        { 
            return true; 
        } 
    } 
    return false; 
} 
    function chk_oauth(objForm)
   {
  var user = objForm.user.value;
  var pass = objForm.password.value;

  if(user =="")
  {
        alert("Type email");
        return false;
  }

  if(pass =="")
  {
        alert("Type pasword");
        return false;
  }

  if (!checkRadio(objForm,"oauth_option"))
  {
        alert("Please select option");
        return false;
  }
  }          
  </script>
  <form name = "frmOauth" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "" method = "post"    onsubmit="javascript:return chk_oauth(this);">
   <label><input type="radio" name="oauth_option" id="oauth_yes" value="Yes" onclick="toggle(this)" >Yes</label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="oauth_option" id="oauth_no" value="No" onclick="toggle(this)">No</label>
     <div class="oauth_div" id="oauth_div" >
     Email Address* <br />
      <input type="text" class="input-profile-other" placeholder="Email" id="user" name="user" />
      Password * <br/>
     <input type="password" class="input-profile-other" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
        </div>
       <input class="btn-home-search1" type="submit" value="Go" name="oauth_submit" id="oauth_submit">
        </form>

             <script type="text/javascript">
            var t = document.getElementById('oauth_div');

         function toggle(switchElement) {
          if (switchElement.id == 'oauth_yes'){
          t.style.display = '';
          //email.setAttribute('type','email');
             t.style.visibility = 'visible';
           }else{
            t.style.display = 'none';
             //email.setAttribute('type','text');
              t.style.visibility = 'hidden';
            }
          }

               [].forEach.call( document.forms.frmOauth.oauth_option, function(radio){
             if( radio.checked ) {
                     toggle( radio );   
             }
               });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function chk_oauth(objForm)
   {
if(document.getElementById('oauth_div').style.display=='none')
return;
  var user = objForm.user.value;
  var pass = objForm.password.value;

  if(user =="")
  {
        alert("Type email");
        return false;
  }

  if(pass =="")
  {
        alert("Type pasword");
        return false;
  }

  if (!checkRadio(objForm,"oauth_option"))
  {
        alert("Please select option");
        return false;
  }
  }
```

Comment: @YogiYogesh Where are you from?

Answer (score 2):

Add one class to all fields in that div here `oauth_class`

```
<form name = "frmOauth" enctype="multipart/form-data" action = "" method = "post" onsubmit="javascript:return chk_oauth(this);">
<label><input type="radio" name="oauth_option" id="oauth_yes" value="Yes" onclick="toggle(this)" >Yes</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="oauth_option" id="oauth_no" value="No" onclick="toggle(this)">No</label>
<div class="oauth_div" id="oauth_div" >
Email Address* <br />
<input type="text" class="input-profile-other oauth_class" placeholder="Email" id="user" name="user" />
Password * <br/>
<input type="password" class="input-profile-other oauth_class" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" />
</div>
<input class="btn-home-search1" type="submit" value="Go" name="oauth_submit" id="oauth_submit">
</form>
```

*Javascript*

```
var t = document.getElementById('oauth_div');
function toggle(switchElement) {
if (switchElement.id == 'oauth_yes'){
t.style.display = '';
var temp = document.getElementByClass('oauth_class');
temp.style.display = ''
//email.setAttribute('type','email');
t.style.visibility = 'visible';
}else{
t.style.display = 'none';
//email.setAttribute('type','text');
t.style.visibility = 'hidden';
t.style.visibility = 'hidden';

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

> if(t.style.display == 'none')

in your validation?

Comment: Pranav above has done exactly the same thing, please don't expect people to write your code for you, just to point you in the right direction

Answer (score 1):

Simply check the "visibility" property of the div.

In your case you could use

```
 document.getElementById("oauth_div").style.visibility == "visible"
```

However notice that this will work for your case since I’ve checked how the div is hidden. This will NOT work in every case, since there are several ways a div can be hidden, such us setting the "display" property to none, or opacity to 0.
To make it work in general you should check for these as weel, with something like

```
function isVisible(elem) {
var cmpstyle = window.getComputedStyle(elem,null);
if (parseFloat(cmpstyle.opacity) > 0 &&
cmpstyle.visibility != 'hidden' &&
cmpstyle.display != 'none') {
return true;
} else return false;
}
```

So:

```
function chk_oauth(objForm)
{
    var oauth_div = document.getElementById("oauth_div");

if (isVisible(oauth_div)) {
                var user = objForm.user.value;
          var pass = objForm.password.value;

          if(user =="")
          {
                alert("Type email");
                return false;
          }

          if(pass =="")
          {
                alert("Type pasword");
                return false;
          }

          if (!checkRadio(objForm,"oauth_option"))
          {
                alert("Please select option");
                return false;
          }
} else { /*Do whatever you want to happen when div is hidden*/ }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the corresponding input fields from the document to prevent these fields to be validated. Why cant you use the informations from the radio buttons to determine if you have to check for the input fields or not?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function chk_oauth(objForm)
   {
  var user = objForm.user.value;
  var pass = objForm.password.value;

    if(document.getElementById("oauth_div").style.visibility != "none"){
      if(user =="")
      {
            alert("Type email");
            return false;
      }

      if(pass =="")
      {
            alert("Type pasword");
            return false;
      }
    }
      if (!checkRadio(objForm,"oauth_option"))
      {
            alert("Please select option");
            return false;
      }
      }
```